# Difference between two dates in Sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I work in Sqlite3 and tried

```
DATEDIFF(days, listing_date, sale_date)
```

But it didn't work. What is the correct way to take a difference between two columns which are timestamps in Sqlite3?

```
id  listing_date    sale_date
1   2012/02/27      2020/02/27
2   2011/06/27      2020/02/17
3   2008/08/03      2020/02/19
4   2012/12/27      2020/02/07
5   2001/02/17      2020/02/29
6   2019/02/01      2020/02/27
7   2018/02/27      2020/02/03
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. The date format should be `yyyy-mm-dd` for everything to work properly. This is based on ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You’ll notice that @forpas’s solution below replaces the characters.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [julianday()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT 
  julianday(replace(sale_date, '/', '-')) - julianday(replace(listing_date, '/', '-'))
FROM tablename
```

You will get the difference in days as a real number.
If your date columns contain a time part then you may get results with decimal places like: `5.1234` which you can [round()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round) or [cast](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) to integer values.
The replacement of `/` with `-` is necessary if you store the dates in the format in your question.

Comment: I was 2 minutes late!